# Add Maven repo into class path

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven repo which contains all of the dependencies needed for a Java project.

How do I add the maven repo into the classpath environment variable so it can be access via the console?

Working with a project that has a bash script to setup the development environment. This also runs some Java code but is can not see any for the dependencies of the project.

Comment: By using the dependencies you need in your pom file which will add them on the classpath? Furthermore I recommend to take a look at the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) which will generate those script files for your...

Answer (score 0):

You can configure either the setting.xml at user level (${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml) or the global level configuration (${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml) by specifying the localRepository element to define the local repository path. Setting the environment variable *MY_M2_REPO*, before running maven, will effectively define the local repository path.

```
<localRepository>${env.MY_M2_REPO}</localRepository>
```

Alternatively, you can use the argument **maven.repo.local** to specify the location of your local repository when running maven.

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.repo.local=/home/user/maven_repo
```